# After I apply intellij-code-formatter.xml, the xml indent fommated as strange form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, mybatis, conventions

env: spring boot 2.6, mybatis, intelliJ

I apply formatter xml.

but I use ctrl + alt + l (window) formatting short cut

then mybatis.xml formatted like below,

which tag can fix this (normal format)? please help me!

I use this formmat xml

```
    <code_scheme name="Exem-coding-convention-v1.2">
  <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="99" />
  <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="1" />
  <option name="IMPORT_LAYOUT_TABLE">
    <value>
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="true" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="java" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="javax" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="org" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="net" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="com" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="io" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="lombok" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
      <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
      <emptyLine />
    </value>
  </option>
  <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="120" />
  <option name="ENABLE_JAVADOC_FORMATTING" value="false" />
  <option name="JD_KEEP_EMPTY_LINES" value="false" />
  <option name="FORMATTER_TAGS_ENABLED" value="true" />
  <XML>
    <option name="XML_ATTRIBUTE_WRAP" value="2" />
    <option name="XML_ALIGN_ATTRIBUTES" value="false" />
    <option name="XML_SPACE_INSIDE_EMPTY_TAG" value="true" />
    <option name="XML_LEGACY_SETTINGS_IMPORTED" value="true" />
  </XML>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    <option name="LINE_COMMENT_AT_FIRST_COLUMN" value="false" />
    <option name="LINE_COMMENT_ADD_SPACE" value="true" />
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_CONTROL_STATEMENT_IN_ONE_LINE" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_DECLARATIONS" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RBRACE" value="1" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS" value="false" />
    <option name="SPACE_AFTER_TYPE_CAST" value="false" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="true" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="THROWS_LIST_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="BINARY_OPERATION_SIGN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="1" />
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="true" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

After I use fommating shortcut, I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNzBi.png)